# Different Page Layouts from picklist

Tags: picklist, page-layout, record-type

I am trying to create 2 different Page Layouts depending on picklist.

**For example.**

1.If One value from that picklist is selected Active or Active with Dev. Work Only
Then the section Publisher Journey should be displayed.(pagelayout 1)

2.If others than the previous are selected the Publisher Journeys section should be gone.(pagelayout 2)

Please advise how can i accomplish this.

Thanks,

Darko

Comment: By section display / gone, do you mean all this is happening on one page? and only part or section of the page is appearing/disappearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create two record types. Each record type can have it's own Page Layout. You should then create a workflow rule that changes the record type, and therefore the Page Layout, of the record depending on what Picklist Value is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information you provided I would say that you should go down the VF path. You will have to create a VF page or a VF Page component to be embedded in the page layout that would contain controlling picklist and dependent Publisher Journeys section.

I would advise against using record types unless above mentioned picklist values do indeed separate records in 2 different types. Otherwise record types should not be used as a means to make UI "dynamic".

Comment: this is good idea but it will take quite allot of time to build this and I am trying to find quick solution meanwhile :)

Comment: Sure, I understand the time pressure. I was simply approaching the problem from best-practice point of view.